# Как вызывать событие клика и считывание input?

Tags: javascript

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gjRYWx

```
<body>
<form>
<div id="letter"></div>
<input type="text" value="" id="city" >
<input type="button">
```

```
 function generateRound(myUser, myBot) {
        var rand = 0;
        rand = 0 + Math.floor(Math.random() * (ab.length + 1));
        LettersDiv.innerHTML = ab[rand];
        var myChoise;
        myChoise = document.getElementById("city").value;
```

Делаю приложенице типа игры в города. Как вы видите, появляется рандомная буква выше input. Так вот после этого я ввожу в input город на эту букву и жму на кнопку. Таким образом, она должна считаться и должно продолжиться выполнение функции. Затем новая итерация, следующая буква и следующее слово.

На данный момент программа ничего не считывает и обрабатывается дальше с пустым значением. (в myChoise пустая строка)

Answer (score 0):

Так у Вас проблема только с кнопкой? Если так, то поставьте обработчик на событие `onclick`, в нём вызывайте свою функцию для обработки клика. Вот пример:

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello, World!";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Нажми!</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: это я понимаю. у меня не считывается input, он не успевает